# Didenterregion is not called in background using regionbootstrap in altbeacon

Tags: android, android-studio, beacon, altbeacon

I am developing a beacon scanning app using `altbeacon` library in android. In the foreground, it is detecting properly. But in the background using `regiobootstrap`, it is not detecting. The `didenterrgion` and `didexitregion` is not calling. Only the `didDetermineStateForRegion` is calling with state 0. I need to launch an activity when a beacon is detected in the background. Kindly help me.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
private static final String TAG = ".MyApplicationName";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private Identifier identifier;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.d(TAG, "App started up");
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    identifier = Identifier.parse("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"); //beacon 1
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(5001);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5001);
```

//Changes made now

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentTitle("Scanning for Beacons");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification Channel ID",
                "My Notification Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("My Notification Channel Description");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
    }
    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);
    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);



    Region region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", identifier, null, null);

    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    super.onCreate();
}



@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    /*regionBootstrap.disable();*/
    Log.i(TAG, "didenterregion");
    Toast.makeText(this, "entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
    // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.i(TAG, "didexitregion!");
    Toast.makeText(this, "exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
    Log.i(TAG, " diddeterminateregion!"  +i);
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Here is my foregroundscanning fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("scannerfragment","oncraeteview");

    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scanning, container, false);

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getActivity());

    bt_scan_again=view.findViewById(R.id.bt_scan_again);

    bt_scan_again.setOnClickListener(this);



    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));


    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5001);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(5001);

     identifier = Identifier.parse("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"); //beacon 1

    region = new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", identifier, null, null);



    return view;

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.bt_scan_again:

            beaconManager.bind(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {



    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
            try {
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
            try {
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                lay_no_offer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lay_having_offer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
            if(state==1){
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }else if(state==0){
                try {
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });


    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", identifier, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }


    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {

                Collections.sort((List<Beacon>) beacons, new Comparator<Beacon>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Beacon o1, Beacon o2) {
                        return Double.compare(o2.getDistance(),( o1.getDistance()));
                    }


                });

                mac1=((List<Beacon>) beacons).get(0).getBluetoothAddress();
                call_offers_api(mac1);



}

 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

    beaconManager.unbind(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "unbineed");
    Log.d("scannerfragment","ondestroyview");
}



  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("scannerfragment","ondestroy");


}




}
```

Comment: Do you detect with this exact code if you are in the foreground?  How about in the background with the screen on?  How long do you wait in the background? . Whatice model and version do you see this on?

Comment: @davidgyoung .yes the same exact code.in background with the screen on ,beacon is detecting same as foreground .When i close the scanning fragment,i am unbinding beacon in ondestroyview.Again when i reopen the app with screen off,i am not getting beacon detected.i waited for 2 minutes.honor 9 lite,android oreo.

Comment: if i register the Myapplication class in android manifest.The foreground scanning class is also not detecting beacons.

Comment: the code does not show the definition of your foregroundscanning fragment, but if it is indeed a Fragment (and not an Activity), you must chain  the  getApplicationContext/bindService/unbindService of the BeaconConsumer methods to the equivalent method on the Activity.  The lack of detection in the background may be the Huawei custom OS blocking scans with the screen off.. Please test with the library reference app to see this works.  I recommend using the reference app as a starting point, then once it's working, modify it one step at a time to meet the needs of your app.

Comment: i have tested with android nougat,its working correctly in background.I did two experiment.First is,i keep my app in background(keeping my home screen visible),i entered into the region it detects the beacon and called my intent and opened the app.Second is,i keep my app opened(app landing screen in visible in foreground),i entered the region,it again detects the beacon and reopened my app once again.I dont want to reopen my app ,if its already in foreground?is there any way?

Comment: If you don't want to open your app, just remove the code that launches the Activity in didEnterRegion.  If you want this to happen but only once, just set a  Boolean flag to true to indicate it was launched onece. And don't launch if the flag is already true.

Comment: ok thankyou.And one more doubt,in how to make my background scan in oreo to 5 seconds once like foreground.In oreo,it takes a long time to scan in Background(when app is not visible).I am struggling with this.please help me

Comment: With Android 8+ you can only scan in the background every ~15 minutes.  If you want scans more often you must use a [foreground service.](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html)

Comment: I have added the code for notification.after i run my app,i switched on my beacon.Then it detects beacon in background and launches my app through didenterregion method.But after that ,i again exited from the region and reenter again that region.In that time,didexitregion and did enter region is not called.Overall,it only detects once initially when in background.I have edited my above code.Kindly see it..

Comment: Ok, this sounds like a different problem than originally asked, yes?  You really should post a new question rather than using this as a dynamic troubleshooting session.   This forum is meant to help others as well and you do so you really need to keep the intent of the original question intact.

Comment: ok thankyou,will post a new question soon